# How to show that $I(V \cap W) \subseteq \sqrt{I(V) + I(W)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been stuck at showing the "obvious" second equality in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WahDt.png) proof for quite some time now. By observing that $V \cap W \subseteq V$ and $V \cap W \subseteq W$ we by the inclusion reversity of ideal map that $I(V) \subseteq I(V \cap W)$ and $I(W) \subseteq I(V \cap W)$. As ideals are closed under addition it follows that $I(V) + I(W) \subseteq I(V \cap W)$, and as I maps to radical ideals we finally have that $\sqrt{I(V) + I(W)} \subseteq I(V \cap W)$.

But I have not made any progress going the other way around. To show that $f \in I(V \cap W)$ implies that $f \in \sqrt{I(V) + I(W)}$ we would have to show that $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $f^m \in I(V) + I(W)$, i.e. $f^m = g + h, g \in I(V), h \in I(W)$.

Comment: One possible approach: when $V\cap W=\emptyset$ this reduces to showing that $1\in I(V)+I(W)$, which might be known or simpler. Then maybe one can bootstrap the general case by writing $V=(V\setminus W)\cup(V\cap W)$ and $W=(W\setminus V)\cup(V\cap W)$, so that (I hope) $I(V) = \sqrt{I(V\setminus W)I(V\cap W)}$ and similarly for $I(W)$. (I assume you're deliberately trying to avoid invoking the ideal-variety correspondence itself.)